# Not able to update Entity Framework stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6, I have a stored procedure (result set with 5 columns) in my DB, when I added it to Entity Framework it generating a class with 5 properties in `.tt` file.

Now I am changing the stored procedure in my DB (result set with 4 columns) and updating it in Entity Framework, but  I am still getting the 5th property which was not in the result set in my class

```
public string RoleName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> RoleId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
public string FullName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> StepNo { get; set; }
public string ADCOId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> UserId1 { get; set; }
```

I deleted the `UserId1` in the stored procedure and updated Entity Framework, but I am still getting `UserId1` property.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you

Comment: Many times this happens with me too.. so i go to edmx select all and delete and again "Update Model From Database". Try this if it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional limitation in the designer. Take a look at [this work](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2203) item on codeplex - it contains a work around for this.